# Why the model with rebar layer shows one sided plastic strain in Abaqus?

Tags: finite-element-method, reinforced-concrete, abaqus, coupling

Using the damaged plasticity model, I modeled a concrete coupled shear wall in Abaqus, once with discrete rebar and once with rebar layers for the slab. I used the general static solver to run the push-over analysis. Although deformation happens on both sides of the wall, Abaqus shows the plastic strain just on one side of the wall in the model with a rebar layer (figure 1). In the model with discrete rebar, I am getting symmetric plastic strain which is logical and correct. Does anyone have an idea why the model with rebar layer shows one-sided plastic strain?[image]

Comment: What is the difference between discrete rebar and rebar layer? What kind of load, and why the symmetrical plastic strain makes sense (both tension and compression steel have plasticized)?

Comment: Discrete rebars are separated truss elements representing mesh in the concrete. The rebar layer is based on the surface or shell element which represents the mesh in the concrete. The load is displacement applied on the middle of the left wall which is exactly on the frontal plane of the system (yellow point). Therefore, I expect to see symmetric behavior.

Comment: I'll check the deflection shape to see whether it meets expectations or not. Note that I am not complete under the claim of "symmetrical is correct" as you have off-center displacement that will cause reverse bending between the two walls.